# Gnome 2.28 using the Super key alone as a keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, shortcuts, key-binding

I'm running Redhat Linux 6.5 with Gnome 2.28.2 desktop.

I'm trying to create a shortcut to open a terminal by pressing *just* the super key (i.e. the windows key or mod4) not a combination of the super key and some other key. The gnome-keybinding-properties gui will not let me enter just a modifier key (it wants something like super+d).

How can I tie this shortcut to just the super key?

I've tried editing .gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/%gconf.xml with no luck. I did this in my previous version of gnome (2.16.0) and also with an ubuntu 13.04 install. But I can't figure out how to do it here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dug through an old computer that had this setting enabled and was able to manually update the config file that made this work (couldn't do it through any gui I found).

The file:

/home/(username)/.gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/%gconf.xml

The contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
    <entry name="run_command_terminal" mtime="1395776965" type="string">
        <stringvalue>Super_L</stringvalue>
</entry>
</gconf>
```

The key for me using "Super_L" as the string value. When edited with the gui it was using "Mod4"